# A smooth map that is singular everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, singularity-theory

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and let $F \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^{d +c}$ be a smooth map whose rank is everywhere equal to $d-1$:

$$\mathrm{rank} (dF_{p}) = d-1 \quad \text{for all $p \in U$.} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Recall that the image of the differential $dF_{p}$ is spanned by the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial F(p)}{\partial u^{1}}, \dotsc, \frac{\partial F(p)}{\partial u^{d}}$.

I have some questions:

1. Does condition \eqref{eq1} imply that one among the partial derivatives of $F$ vanishes identically?
2. Could it happen that, while all partial derivatives are nowhere zero, one of them (say the first) is in the span of the others? Here I mean that

$$\dfrac{\partial F(p)}{\partial u^{1}} \in \mathrm{span} \left( \dfrac{\partial F(p)}{\partial u^{2}}, \dotsc, \dfrac{\partial F(p)}{\partial u^{d}}\right)\quad \text{for all $p \in U$.}$$

3. If the answer to the second question is *yes*, can we then find an example?

Comment: The answer to 1. is no: consider $F(x,y) = (x+y,x+y)$ (so that $d=2$,$c=0$). So is the answer to 2.: there is no reason that one specific partial derivative is a combination of the others everywhere. This is true punctually, but the index $i$ such that $\partial_iF(p) \in \mathrm{span}\{\partial_jF(p), j \neq i\}$ will depend on $p$.

Comment: @Didier Thanks for the feedback! So you are saying that it is never possible for one specific partial derivative to be a combination of the others everywhere?

Comment: Of course it is possible in some specific cases (like the example I gave for 1.), but in full generality there is no reason that it holds.